# How to understand atomics in a freestanding C or C++ implementation?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, c11

C11 and C++11 define atomics in terms of threads of execution. Whereas in a hosted environment it is clear what a thread is, it is rather a vague term in a freestanding language implementation.

1. How to formally understand atomics specified in C11 and C++11 in a freestanding implementation where all threads must be implemented inside the program? For example: is an ISR a separate thread of execution?
2. Why did the standard committees define atomics in terms of threads and not simply in the domain of code ordering?
3. Are there any embedded compilers already supporting C11/C++11 atomics besides gcc?

Comment: Do note C++11 defines *thread* in `[intro.multithread]/1`.

Comment: If you only have ISR's, rather than multiple processors/cores, I'd say the relevant part of the standard is the one on signals, rather than threads.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, removed the sentence from the question.

Comment: @EOF I would say the same, but formally is an ISR a signal handler from the standard perspective?

Comment: It's not clear to me what "ordered" means in "ordered atomics". Atomics prevent data races; they do not, and cannot, guarantee ordering.

Comment: @Pete Becker Please read this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order . It may explain why C11 and C++11 atomics are caled ordered.

Comment: @mrn - I was intimately involved in the design and documentation for C++ atomics; they are not called "ordered atomics" in the standard, just "atomics". In some contexts it makes sense to talk about "weakly ordered atomics" as a subset, but if you're asking about the specifications of atomics in the C++ standard, "atomics" is sufficient and much more clear.

Comment: @Pete Becker - I have removed the term "ordered" as you suggested. However I still don't understand why you say that an atomic cannot guarantee ordering. This is my original question reworded: why atomics are defined in terms of data races and not in terms of ordering? How to understand data races in a unicore system with asynchronous ISRs? And finally if atomics cannot guarantee ordering then how to understand such a gcc implementation that supports atomics but does not support C++ memory model --> https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html?

Comment: @mrn -- I was a bit too aggressive there. But only a little bit. <g> Memory order is fundamentally about **visibility**: based on the memory order arguments, atomic accesses ensure that various earlier non-atomic changes are visible in the future. So in that sense it's about ordering. What I meant was that atomics do not guarantee any order between simultaneous **atomic** accesses; they do guarantee that such accesses are not data races, and that's, of course, critical.

Comment: @Pete Becker Thanks for your explanation, I will use more precise words in the future. So my original question could be rephrased as: does the visibility constraints of atomics in C11 and C++11 apply also to a freestanding implementation with asynchronous ISRs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My somewhat mechanistic (and somewhat handwaving) approach to this kind of question is that atomics guarantee three things: reads and writes won't get torn by a context switch (so you only see values that were actually stored in the variable); caches get flushed (so you don't see stale values); and the compiler can't move instructions across an atomic operation (so operations that occur logically before an atomic access in fact occur before that access). Note that I've tried to avoid any notion of "thread" here, although it gets a bit labored.

If you're writing your own threading mechanism, these properties are obviously important. They are orthogonal to the details of the threading mechanism that you're using.

For signal handlers, they give you a place to stand when you need to examine values from the code executed in the signal handler and when the signal handler needs to modify values that the rest of the program cares about.

I'm not sure whether the standard formally addresses ISR's (pretty sure it doesn't), but from this mechanistic perspective, an ISR is no different from a signal that doesn't come from a call to `raise`. It's just an asynchronous function call, and it occupies stack space that it gets from the thread that gets interrupted. It's definitely **not** a thread; it's a parasite on an existing thread. So for an ISR I'd go with the guarantees for signals rather than the guarantees for threads.

Comment: One thing I am still wondering is why the standard did not define the atomics based on the three guarantees you wrote, without the notion of "thread". If it did, it would make no doubt what an atomic means for a bare-metal language implementation.

Comment: @mrn - I think it's precisely because what I wrote is mechanistic and hand-waving. <g> The standard tries to define the semantics of C++ in terms of an abstract machine, and it currently has no notion of "tearing" or "cache". Indeed, there is very little in the abstract machine about memory, and that's  deliberate, to avoid over-containing systems. If you look carefully, you'll see that when you call `operator new` or `operator delete`, the only promise you get is that the first "allocates storage" and that the second "reclaims ... storage"....

Comment: ... So for atomics, the primary use is to communicate values between threads, and the definitions are in terms of what happens when values are shared between threads.

Comment: @Peter Becker Ok, thanks for the explanation. Probably I would see the probems if I tried to write the standard myself.

Answer (score 3):

Atomics are to deal with race conditions, so without threads they make almost no sense. The only other context where races may occur are with signal handlers, and there the C standard offers the concept of lock-freeness.

Seen like that there is no difference between freestanding and hosted environments. Threads and atomics are optional features, and if a freestanding environment supports both, it must comply to the specification of both. If it only supports atomics, it can provide lock-free atomic types for signal handlers, but the other atomic types then are useless.